Hide all following sections from minitoc
I have a chapter with 5 sections. How do I hide the last two from a minitoc?
What I want is if I have this:
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\chapter{This chapter is listed in the contents page}
\minitoc
\section{1: appears in the minitoc}
\section{2: appears in the minitoc}
\section{3: appears in the minitoc}

% A command to stop "counting" the next sections

\section{4: does not appear in the minitoc}
\section{5: does not appear in the minitoc}


\end{document

Is there any way I can hide all following section? Thanks!

You can do this with etoc the following way:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}
\etocignoredepthtags
\tableofcontents

\chapter{This chapter is listed in the contents page}
\etocobeydepthtags
\etocsettagdepth{hide}{none}
\etocsettagdepth{show}{all}

\localtableofcontents

\section{1: appears in the minitoc}
\section{2: appears in the minitoc}
\section{3: appears in the minitoc}

\etocdepthtag.toc{hide}
\section{4: does not appear in the minitoc}

some text

\section{5: does not appear in the minitoc}
\etocdepthtag.toc{show}

some text

\end{document}

Compile at least twice.  Notice that the main table of contents does show the last two sections.  But the chapter local one does not:

I assumed that the two sections must not be ignored in the main table of contents, but if you want them ignored there, simply remove the line \etocignoredepthtags and move the two lines \etocsettagdepth... to before \tableofcontents (or to the preamble of the document).
To get the produced "minitoc" look like with minitoc package, you will need to code it yourself using the etoc interface described in its documentation.
As a starter, you can modify the above code sample to contain
\etocsettocstyle{\noindent\textbf{\contentsname}\par
                 \vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
                 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\bfseries}
                {\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
                 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par}

\localtableofcontents

which produces

It mimics the style of minitoc with some differences.  For example the page numbers are not influenced by the issued \bfseries.  This is due to a \normalfont from the LaTeX kernel code for the page number.
Simplest to change that is to load package tocloft and use its interface like this:
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc}
...
...
\chapter{foo}
... (use same code as previously shown)
\etocsettocstyle{\noindent\textbf{\contentsname}\par
                 \vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
                 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par
                 \renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont\bfseries}%
                 \renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont\bfseries}}
                {\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
                 \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par}

\localtableofcontents
... and same code as previously shown

which produces

Recall to compile enough times after adding or removing a section.

Works like a charm! thanks!
